# c++: how to ask for a file name and open it?

Tags: c++, string, ifstream

I'm struggling a bit here, I have code that looks similar to this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ifstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string filename;
    cout << "Enter the filename: ";
    cin >> filename;
    ifstream myfile(filename);

    //code that does stuff, eg:
    while (myfile >> thing) {
        mydata[i] = thing;
        i = i + 1; //etc, this *isn't* an issue
    }
}
```

The main problem is that it doesn't seem to compile with g++ but I'm sure I have this working before. I read somewhere it was the `string filename;` bit that was broken, but I don't know how else to ask for a file name other than storing it as a `string`. Can anyone help? Also should I use `<fstream>` or `<ifstream>` I don't really see a difference. Thank you.

Comment: `cin >> filename >> endl;` Why are you trying to shove stuff to `std::endl`?

Comment: Oh, er, I don't know, that's not an issue, that's me typing quickly.

Comment: And use `getline()` if `filename` contains spaces.

Comment: What is the error you're receiving. BTW it should `<fstream>`.

Comment: like @0x499602D2 said, we need the error message

Comment: @OMGtechy ok, I'm out at the moment, I'll try and post what the compiler complains about but I think the answer below fixes it.

Comment: `<ifstream>` does not exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first error you need to overcome is [this one](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/45289ef55277c589):

```
main.cpp:3:20: fatal error: ifstream: No such file or directory
 #include <ifstream>
                    ^
compilation terminated.
```

Indeed, this header does not exist. You probably meant `fstream`.

Once that is corrected, [the crux of your issue is](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2b7b840a1ad83192):

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:11:29: error: no matching function for call to 'std::basic_ifstream<char>::basic_ifstream(std::string&)'
     ifstream myfile(filename);
```

This is because `fstream` constructors, in C++98 and C++03, did not take string arguments. This was a sort of legacy oversight, fixed in C++11.

You have two choices:

- Switch to C++11 ([demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b86276e05bc97b66))
- Pass a C-style string instead ([demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fb3b6950dc82ee0f))

  ```
  ifstream myfile(filename.c_str());
  ```

<sub>In both of the above examples, I've had to remove your entire `while` loop because it references symbols not declared in your program. When reporting a problem, please take more care, and present a [testcase](http://sscce.org) that contains *only* the problem you're trying to solve.</sub>

Comment: Ok, thanks you answered my question. I didn't know about the `.c_str()` so that was helpful. Any explanation about what it does different?
Also, you say take more care, but I wasn't providing complete code because I said the issue wasn't there, I knew that part compiled correctly in my program so I didn't want to distract people with variables not related to the problem but I did want to show what I was trying to achieve.

Comment: @captainjamie: As someone who doesn't know why the program isn't compiling, you are not qualified to decide what is and isn't relevant. Plus, it makes _my_ life more difficult when I have to extract pieces of code that _definitely_ won't compile (because you did not declare the required variables), whilst adding absolutely nothing to the question.

Comment: @captainjamie: `.c_str()` returns a pointer to the internal `char` array used by the `std::string`. The data is the same, but the way you access it is different. It's just that IOStreams were updated only relatively recently to take a `std::string` directly.

Comment: @elisa: Did you mean to post that comment on some other question? I don't understand its relevance here.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't have C++11 support, you need to pass a `const char*` to the `ifstream` constructor. You can do so like this:

```
ifstream myfile(filename.c_str());
```